# Can not obtain correct Text field input in onLoad() method, when text was entered by JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to pass a value entered by JQuery in a text field to text INPUT towards my ASP.NET backend handler that looks at respective ASP.NET control's Text property.

It turns out that

```
  $("#inputid").val(mynewvalue);
```

call does update visible text in my text field, but nevertheless I do not receive it when I examine control's Text function in asp.net in onLoad() method that is called after postback.

When onLoad method finishes and further postback work is happening, that is, other routines are called, only then textbox's Text property returns what was entered there by jquery.

Maybe I just have no right to examine these fields in onLoad() method?

I however need to get that Text property already on onLoad stage. I was thinking if there is some way to modify VALUE

Comment: On page (it's a custom control, but anyway)  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ContainerID"  ClientIDMode="AutoID"   />

Comment: I am adding stuff to it using $("#id").val(value) - it appears in the field. In onLoad() method of page I am querying data using ContainerID.Text property.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have runat="server" on your textbox control. My guess is that you don't (if I understand the question!)

Comment: I do have the attribute runat="server"